# PopupCenter by opening new window instead of overwriting the previous one

Tags: javascript, html

Can the PopupCenter function open a new window instead of overwriting the previously opened window? I tried to add `target="_blank"` but it does not work.

I have the code written as below:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:PopupCenter('<%= strUrl_New %>', 1000, 700);" target="_blank" class="link10">Submit Form</a><br>
<a href="javascript:PopupCenter('<%= strUrl_List %>', 1000, 700);" target="_blank" class="link10">View Form</a><br>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
  var top = (screen.height - h) / 2;
  var params = "width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
  params += ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left;
  params += ", directories=no";
  params += ", location=no";
  params += ", menubar=no";
  params += ", resizable=yes";
  params += ", scrollbars=yes";
  params += ", status=no";
  params += ", toolbar=no";

  newwin = window.open(url, title, params);
  if (window.focus) { newwin.focus(); }
  //return false;
}
```

For instance, the link for submit form and view form will open seperate windows. Is it possible to achieve this? Need some help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to give every link a different title

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:PopupCenter('http://www.xtf.dk','xtf','900','500');">xtf</a><br>
<a href="javascript:PopupCenter('http://www.xtf.dk','xtf2','900','500');">xtf2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:PopupCenter('http://www.xtf.dk','xtf2','900','500');">xtf3</a>
<script>
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
  var top = (screen.height - h) / 2;
  var params = "width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
  params += ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left;
  params += ", directories=no";
  params += ", location=no";
  params += ", menubar=no";
  params += ", resizable=yes";
  params += ", scrollbars=yes";
  params += ", status=no";
  params += ", toolbar=no";

  newwin = window.open(url, title, params);
  if (window.focus) { newwin.focus(); }
  //return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first two links in my example open in different windows but not the third, because it has the same title as link nr2